# Find device type(smartphone/tablet) in android

Tags: android

How can I find the device is a smart phone or table through my program? I tried with all fields of android.os.Build class. The info which I got is

OS Version: 2.6.35.7(DXKL2)
OS API Level: 10
Device: GT-S5360
Model (and Product): GT-S5360 (GT-S5360)
Board: totoro
Brand: samsung
CPU_ABI: armeabi
Display: GINGERBREAD.DXKL2
Fingerprint: samsung/GT-S5360/GT-S5360:2.3.6/GINGERBREAD/DXKL2:user/release-keys
Host: DELL152
Id: GINGERBREAD
Manufacturer: samsung
Type: user
User: root

This information is not helpful for me. Can someone tell me how to find it?

Answer (score 3):

What do you really want to know? Do you want to know if the device can make calls? Do you want to know how big the screen is? There are APIs for finding out those things.

'Smartphone' and 'Tablet' are marketing labels - they don't really mean a whole lot at a technical level, because one could make a tablet sized device that makes calls over the cell network, and one could make a phone-sized device that doesn't have any network beyond wi-fi!

Tell us what you actually want to know, and we can point you to the proper APIs.

Comment: @Michel thanks for your reply. Actually, in my app I need to send the device type to my server. At server side they are generating the reports based on this device type. Is it clear for you?

Comment: @VenuGopal - then send the model/product up to the server and let them figure out what that means. The problem is that you've got some products on the market that bump pretty hard up against the line - like the Samsung Galaxy Note - is that a small tablet? Or a big smartphone? It's kind of arbitrary, so it's not something that the OS can tell you. If you REALLY MUST answer the question on the device, then I'd go with the presence or absence of the cellular calling as the thing to go by.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the screen density calling this code:

```
int screen_density = (getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK);

if (screen_density == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE || screen_density == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
     //The device is a tablet or at least has the screen density of a tablet
}
```

You can also get the screen size with the code below:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Finally, keep in mind that android Honeycomb(3.+) runs only in tablet so you can check the version of Android using:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

if(currentapiVersion == android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ||
   currentapiVersion == android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1 || 
   currentapiVersion == android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {

  //The device is a tablet
}
```

**EDIT**: Just to clarrify, the above code asumes that you are interested in device screen size and density for classifying a device as tablet. As stated from the answer of Michael Kohne there are many technical aspects that makes this classification difficult (if not impossible).

Hope this helps:)

Comment: There are also tablets running on ICS Android 4.0 so the currentApiVersion check is not very useful.